# Regex to match repeated (unknown) substrings

Tags: python, arrays, regex

I'm trying to find "laughter words" or similar such as `hahaha`, `hihihi`, `hueheu` within user messages. My current approach is as follows:

```
>>> substring_list = ['ha', 'ah', 'he', 'eh', 'hi', 'ih', 'ho', 'hu', 'hue']
>>> pattern_core = '|'.join(substring_list)
>>> self.regex_pattern = re.compile(r'\b[a-z]*(' + pattern_core + r'){2,}[a-z]*\b', re.IGNORECASE)
```

The `[a-z]*` allows for some leeway when it comes to typos (e.g., `ahhahah`). In principle this works reasonably well. The problem is that it needs to be maintained in the sense that `substring_list` needs to be updated to match new forms of "laughter words" (e.g., adding `xi`); "laughter words" seem to vary quite noticable between countries.

Now I wonder if I can somehow find words based on repeated patterns (of sizes, say, 2-4) without knowing the individual pattern. For example, `hurrhurr` contains `hurr` as repeated pattern. In the ideal case I can (a) match `hurrhurr` and (b) identify the core pattern `hurr`. I have no idea if this is possible with regular expressions.

Comment: Your substring_list currently matches `hurrhurr`, since `hu` is defined already.

Comment: @l'L'l notice there's a `{2,}` quantifier repeating the group.

Comment: @Mariano: What am I suppose to notice about it?

Comment: @l'L'l it won't match `hurrhurr` because `hu` is not repeated 2+ consecutive times

Comment: @Mariano: Try it with the string `"she laughed hahahaha & hurrhurr"`... it picks up the `hu` portion, which I had mentioned already; I'm still not seeing your point.

Comment: It does not match `hurrhurr`; just tested it. As Mariano said, there are no (at least two) consecutives appearences of `hu`. 'huhurrhurr' would match, sure.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the accepted answer is overly complicated, matches things it shouldn't, and does not provide the desired output.

Comment: @7stud: You're right, it matches more than I would like to, e.g., `banana`, with `an` as twice repeated pattern. However, I would argue that this is a principle problem, and I expected it to happen. If I wouldn't know the fruit, `banana` looks similar to `muhaha`. So I have to tweak the solution towards a reasonable trade-off between recall and precision (but yeat, probably with focus on precision).

Comment: Okay, let's concentrate on the result you wanted, i.e. returning the core pattern along with the whole pattern.  Does the accepted answer do that?

Comment: Yes, it does. This is why I accepted it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This regex will do it:

```
\b[a-z]*?([a-z]{2,}?)\1+[a-z]*?\b
```

Usage:

```
self.regex_pattern = re.compile(r'\b[a-z]*?([a-z]{2,}?)\1+[a-z]*?\b', re.IGNORECASE)
```

[Here's a working demo](https://regex101.com/r/dC6kA3/4).

The gist is similar to what you were doing, but the "core" is different. The heart of the regex is this piece:

```
([a-z]{2,}?)\1+
```

The logic is to find a group consisting of 2 or more letters, then match the same group (`\1`) one or more additional times.

Comment: Ed, this works great! The notion `\1` to refer to a group is the part I was missing. How can I now use this to extract the repeated pattern 'hurr'? Like "Find the repeated pattern, and return the first appearance".

Comment: @Christian Use `re.findall`, then access the results, as in `results = re.findall(pattern, string, re.IGNORECASE)
print(results)`.  Here's a demo: http://ideone.com/nCxPj1

Comment: @bobblebubble Good point. That was a carryover from something else I was playing with. Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

> In the ideal case I can (a) match hurrhurr and (b) identify the core
>   pattern hurr. I have no idea if this is possible with regular expressions.

```
import re

string = """hahaha, huehue, heehee, 
            axaxaxax, x the theme, ------, hhxhhxhhx, 
            bananas, if I imagine, HahHaH"""

pattern = r"""
    (
        \b               #Match a word boundary...

        ( 
            [a-z]{2,}?   #Followed by a letter, 2 or more times, non-greedy...
        )                #Captured in group 2,        

        \2+              #Followed by whatever matched group 2, one or more times...

        \b               #Followed by a word boundary.
    )                    #Capture in group 1.
"""

results = re.findall(pattern, string, re.X|re.I)
print(results)

--output:--
[('hahaha', 'ha'), ('huehue', 'hue'), ('heehee', 'hee'), ('axaxaxax', 'ax'), ('hhxhhxhhx', 'hhx'), ('HahHaH', 'Hah')]
```

Comment: This won't match, for example, `heehee` or `hurrhurr`. It will, however, match `if I imagine` or `bananas`. That seems wrong. https://regex101.com/r/qY4vP2/1

Comment: @Mariano, Yes, it will.

Comment: @7stud I see you've revised the regex, but it will still match `if I imagine` and `bananas` (or, as Mariano says, `-------` or `x the theme`). See http://ideone.com/FKKiRT